# Numpy array: How to add title?

Tags: arrays, numpy

I have two numpy arrays like below and I want to add a title/name (i.e. "verts" and "faces") in front of each. Could you please tell me how to do that? Thank you

I have:

```
array([array([[-0.03136266, -0.03174387,  0.3912825 ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.77104884,  0.3478601 ],
       [-0.03345102, -0.12221089, -0.20077045]]),

array ([[232, 143, 120],
       [190, 187, 152],
       [143, 200, 120], dtype=int32)], dtype=object)
```

I want:

```
array({'verts': array([[-0.03136266, -0.03174387,  0.3912825 ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.77104884,  0.3478601 ],
       [-0.03345102, -0.12221089, -0.20077045]]), 

'faces': array ([[232, 143, 120],
       [190, 187, 152],
       [143, 200, 120], dtype=int32)], dtype=object)
```

Comment: So you want a dictionary of numpy arrays? The data structure you desire is not a numpy array.

Comment: Use `pandas` if you want column and row names

Comment: You can make a `dict` with titltes as key, and array as values.  I don't see any value to embedding that in a object dtype array.

Answer (score 0):

Basically logic is that :
**1.** First we convert given array of array to list using this instruction `list(i.tolist() for i in C))`.
**2.** Then finally create a `dict-object` for our purpose using `list comprehension`.
**3.** Finally convert this object into `ndarray object` using `array(dict_)`

```
from numpy import array

C = array([array([[-0.03136266, -0.03174387,  0.3912825 ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.77104884,  0.3478601 ],
       [-0.03345102, -0.12221089, -0.20077045]]), 
       
       array([[232, 143, 120],
       [190, 187, 152],
       [143, 200, 120]], dtype='int32')], dtype='object')

dict_ = {i:j for i,j in zip(['verts', 'faces'],list(i.tolist() for i in C))}
print(dict_)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
{
    'verts': [[-0.03136266, -0.03174387, 0.3912825],
              [0.0, 0.77104884, 0.3478601],
              [-0.03345102, -0.12221089, -0.20077045]],
    'faces': [[232, 143, 120], [190, 187, 152], [143, 200, 120]]
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @exploore-x Much appreciated.
I went through your 3 steps and almost everything seems fine. The only thing I'm missing is the phrase ":array" after 'vertices' and 'faces'